# Find hard drive volume number in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Read carefully: I need to identify the **volume number** *not* the serial of D:.

This *does not* provide the volume number...

```
vol D:
```

The *volume number* for C:\ is...

**\Device\HarddiskVolume2**

I was unable to find the information in the Computer Management/Disk Manager utility.

So how do I determine the D: hard drive volume number?

Comment: Run diskpart -> list volume

Comment: Good question and good answer. Voted up so you can vote up the answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and type `diskpart`. When diskpart loads type `list volume` to obtain the currently assigned volumes, including their numbers.

Anyone interested in Windows disk and partition management should read up on diskpart - very powerful, easy to use and makes imaging a doddle!

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and type `mountvol` and look at the end of the result you will find every drive(disk partition) with its volume number ;)

works on win10 also

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and type `fltmc volumes`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the original question, if you read it carefully. "Volume number" is confusing because the number reported by diskpart is not the same number that appears in the device path under "volume name" reported by fltmc. The OP clearly wants the latter. For example, diskpart reports my C: as "Volume 4", whereas fltmc gives "\Device\HarddiskVolume6".